# Responsive CSS grid won't allow for proper spacing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page with HTML and CSS3, unfortunately the last time I coded CSS3 wasn't a thing yet. I am trying to put images in a reactive grid, however this grid keeps coming out looking  like this:

As you can see the other items aren't showing because I assume it does not think there is enough room, here is the responsive CSS code I am using:

http://pastebin.com/qAZMCRby

Here is the CSS I am using on that DIV:

```
.portfolio-section {
}
.portfolio-box {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.js .portfolio-box {
    opacity:0;
}
.portfolio-box:hover .portfolio-caption {
    opacity:1;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=95)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=95);
}
.portfolio-image {
    margin:0;
}
.portfolio-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 0 #000000;
}
.portfolio-caption:before, 
.portfolio-title {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.portfolio-caption:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
}
.portfolio-caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    opacity:0;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:rgb(127, 140, 141);
    background:rgba(127, 140, 141, 0.85);
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transition:0.2s all linear;
        -moz-transition:0.2s all linear;
            transition:0.2s all linear;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.portfolio-title {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    margin:0;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.portfolio-category {
    display:block;
    font-size:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.des {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;
    /* height:250px;
    overflow:hidden;*/
}
```

And here is the code of the page:

```
 <!-- portfolio box 1 -->
            <div class="grid-25 mobile-grid-50 tablet-grid-33">
                <a class="portfolio-popup" href="10607992_380327985449549_704859460_n.jpg">
                <div class="portfolio-box">       
                <figure class="portfolio-image"><img src="10607992_380327985449549_704859460_a.jpg" alt="ASUS N550 Performance Laptop, $1200" title="ASUS N550 Performance Laptop, $1200"></figure><!-- close portfolio image -->
                <div class="portfolio-caption">
                    <h3 class="portfolio-title">$1200<span class="portfolio-category">ASUS N550 Performance Laptop, $1200</span></h3>
                </div><!-- close portfolio caption -->               
                </div>
            </a><div class = "des">ASUS N550 Performance Laptop, $1200<form method="post" target="_top">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">
</form></div>
                 </span>
            </div>
            <!-- close portfolio -->
```

I feel like an idiot. The only thing I could do to "resolve" this issue is to add "height:250px;
        overflow:hidden;" to the DIV but then it just looks awful. I don't need it to be in an exact grid (but it would be nice) - I just need it not to mess up with an extra line of text is added to an item. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using nth-child in the responsive CSS sheet , I believe, if there is a better way let me know, here is my simple code modification.

```
  .mobile-grid-50 {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    /* <IE7> */
    *width: expression(Math.floor(0.5 * (this.parentNode.offsetWidth - parseFloat(this.parentNode.currentStyle.paddingLeft) - parseFloat(this.parentNode.currentStyle.paddingRight))) + "px");
    /* </IE7> */
  }
  .mobile-grid-50:nth-child(2n+1) {
clear: both;
}


  .tablet-grid-33 {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%;
    /* <IE7> */
    *width: expression(Math.floor(0.33333 * (this.parentNode.offsetWidth - parseFloat(this.parentNode.currentStyle.paddingLeft) - parseFloat(this.parentNode.currentStyle.paddingRight))) + "px");
    /* </IE7> */
  }

  .tablet-grid-33:nth-child(3n+3) {
clear: both;
}

  .grid-25 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    /* <IE7> */
    *width: expression(Math.floor(0.25 * (this.parentNode.offsetWidth - parseFloat(this.parentNode.currentStyle.paddingLeft) - parseFloat(this.parentNode.currentStyle.paddingRight))) + "px");
    /* </IE7> */

  }
  .grid-25:nth-child(4n+3) {
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason the 5th grid item won't align correctly is because the auto height is different among the previous 4 items (their description text length are different)

I solved this kind of question before many times. 
3 methods

1. dynamically echo a `<div class="clear" style="clear:both" ></div>` in the end of the responsive row. 
   @tony to your reply, u can use iterator to count how many grid items has been displayed within a row. here is a live website also loop its grid items from db ttp://glow-raspberry.com/product/ketone/  in which it used class="clear" to align all items responsively.
2. create a function to loop calculating the max-height of all your grid items and applies it to the rest of the grid item with the max-height fixed value that the function returned. compared to the 1st method, i still prefer the first one cause it's more light-weighted.
3. a third method is put the fulltext in the title attribute of your description div while using an excerpt function to return fix-length text for description display, which won't create different heights among grid items but the drawback is you can only see part of the description text ended with "..." until you hover on it to see the full string title.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, however there is a slight problem... each of those items are being called from a database using PHP, as well as the images. Thus option 1 is out of the question unless I could do something like that after each line of code.

Option 2 is a little implausible in my case due to the fact that I am pulling from a MySQL database and each caption can be 0-65535 characters long, meaning some items could have very titles and others could be blank. Could you expand on the 3rd option?

Comment: using iterator viralbe to count how many grid items has been displayed.

Comment: That is going to be problematic due to the responsiveness of the grid, it is 2 items across on mobile, 3 on tablet, 4 on high resolutions.

Comment: see if u can get some clues from this url: ttps:/glow-raspberry.com/product/ketone/ ' <?php foreach ($cols as $key ):  ?>
 
 <div class="grid-item-container">
  <img class="griditem-image" src="<?php echo $col->imageurl; ?>"" />
  <div class="griditem-text">$col->descriptiontext</div>
 </div>  

 <?php if (($key + 1) % 3 == 0): ?>
   <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

 <?php endforeach ?>'

Comment: wouldn't that only work if the gird wasn't responsive?

Comment: if you view source on the demo site on the above link, you'll see actually it's been using bootstrap 3 responsive framework. I removed the long class name is just for u to understand it easier. you can wrap it with responsive class there is not much difference.

Comment: Yes, but how would php help in this situation?

Comment: dear tony,u previously said "each of those items are being called from a database using PHP." so i supposed you used php to do it.

Comment: yes, that is correct, but since the grid is moving dynamically based on client side script wouldn't (with either 2, 3, 4 columns) how would PHP help me out by clearing every X items?

Comment: would you mind elaborating on this: "I removed the long class name is just for u to understand it easier. you can wrap it with responsive class there is not much difference." - I am not quite following.

Comment: ah, in source code, the gird item are using class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 padding-0" such a long class to fullfill auto responsive in different views(largescreen, md for tablets, sm and xs for mobile resolutions). so @mediaqueries actually did those resposive things for u to change columns from 4,3,2 1 in a bootstrap 3 framework.

Comment: Okay, I am following, but I am still unable to understand how to resolve this issue without rewriting the entire code and it sounds like you know how to, I am just not up to snuff on my CSS and HTML to follow.

Comment: u need to understand using css @media queries to settle responsive alignment from column 4 3 2 1 etc , as for inserting clear:both tags u can use php or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is so much markup and CSS for such a simple layout.

### Flexible Product Grid

This is a simple, no-frills, concept.

#### The HTML is stripped bare

```
<div class="product">    
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />    
  <p>Long Product Description, $2194</p>    
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>  
</div>
```

#### A sprinkle of CSS

- The products are aligned with `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`
- The products are given a percentage width and will re-size *naturally*. In this example, 25% gets four across.
- `box-sizing: border-box` incorporates the padding into the width and heights. This is important as we can give each product some padding and still declare a reliable percentage width
- The product description is given a min-height to line up the buttons at the bottom of each product
- The product image will re-size in proportion thanks to `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%`

#### Complete Example

Note how the closing div tag is right next to the next opening div tag: `</div><div>`. This is to [prevent the gap that occurs with inline elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Re-size your browser window to see the grid re-size fluidly.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.product {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.product p {
  min-height: 50px;
  /* This can change with @media */
}
.product button {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #DDD;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border: none;
}
.product img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
    <p>Long Product Description, $2194</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>
  </div><div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
    <p>Short, $2194</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>
  </div><div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
    <p>Long Product Description, $2194</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>
  </div><div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
    <p>Short, $2194</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>
  </div><div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
    <p>Long Product Description, $2194</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>
  </div><div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
    <p>Short, $2194</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>
  </div><div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
    <p>Long Product Description, $2194</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>
  </div><div class="product">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400" alt="image" />
    <p>Short, $2194</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Buy Now">Buy Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a template for a lot of my coding and it has a bunch of things that are desirable such as a rollover effect, image popup, and a few other things. I believe if I change the CSS on that it will cease to work. Furthermore that CSS will show 4 columns across most resolutions, correct? I am trying to go for 2 across on mobile, 3 on tablet, and 4 on computer.

Comment: @tony - it's true that you would have to build those affects on top of this, so my idea above is only a good idea if you want to get your hands dirty :) Using `@media` we could change from two across (50% width), three across (33.33%), and 4 across (25%) dependant on device / screensize.

Comment: the template I am using is http://themeforest.unitedthemes.com/themes/brooklyn/yellow/ - so after all is said and done, I think my hannds would be very dirty if not raw.